# When I merge accounts, will I be contacted through email or phone? And how do I decide which account it's going to be through?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I'd like to have my account through Yahoo, but join my Google account to it, because I don't want to lose all my progress.

Comment: You won’t lose any “progress”, that’s the point of the merge. It’s almost certainly going to go through email, this is an international site after all. I’m not really sure what main account is chosen though, likely either the one you’re logged in on when contacting or the higher rep one though.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: It *used* to be, at least, that you'd indicate which account to keep and which to merge by changing your **profile text** to `merge keep` and `merge delete`. Not sure if that's still the case.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what that means, but I think I might understand. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that they always keep the profile of the account with the lower id (which will be older). It would be smart to save a copy of your desired profile pic and summary just in case.

You should get all communication via email, never phone call. I’m not sure which email they will contact but it could be both.

Comment: Okay. I understand now. Thank you.